# position parameter incorrect that cause error i.e. Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android

I am new on android and i am self learner i got the error during full screen activity i.e.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard, PID: 25646
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard/com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard.FullImageActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
               Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                  at com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard.NoticeListAdapter.getItem(NoticeListAdapter.java:38)
                  at com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard.FullImageActivity.onCreate(FullImageActivity.java:36)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

My NoticeListAdpater code is

```
public class NoticeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private  int layout;
private ArrayList<Notice> foodsList;

public NoticeListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Notice> foodsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.foodsList = foodsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return foodsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return foodsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName, txtPrice,notice_id;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row = view;
    NoticeListAdapter.ViewHolder holder = new NoticeListAdapter.ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder.notice_id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.notice_id);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (NoticeListAdapter.ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Notice food = foodsList.get(position);


    holder.notice_id.setText(food.getNoticeId());
    holder.txtName.setText(food.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(food.getPrice());

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(food.getImageUrl(), options);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return row;

}
```

}

and full image activity code is

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Notice> list;
private ArrayList<Notice> foodsList;


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return foodsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    NoticeListAdapter imageAdapter = new NoticeListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource((Integer) imageAdapter.getItem(position));
}
```

}

and i used on set item click listener on the main page to show the image on full screen, my set item click listener code is on main page

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

but i got error that is pasted above plz help mee.
Thank you.

Comment: `return foodsList.get(position);` you try to fetch item from position 0 when array length is 0

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty to your `Adapter` in this part:

```
 list = new ArrayList<>();
    NoticeListAdapter imageAdapter = new NoticeListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
```

As you can see, you are creating an ArrayList and passing it to adapter with no values.
To fix this, try to insert some data in your list or change your adapter to avoid this behavior.

Comment: i add the data into list
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            // int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id"));
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            String imageUrl = cursor.getString(3);

            list.add(new Notice(id,name, price, imageUrl));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.project.sumit.diems_onlinenoticeboard.SQLiteHelper.getData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference